# Imagemagick Batch operation conditional on Filesize - How?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, mogrify

I'm running `Imagemagick` on a command line Ubuntu terminal in Windows 10  - using the built in facility in Windows 10 - the Ubuntu App.

I am a complete linux novice but have installed `imagemagick` in the above environment.

My task - Auto remove the black(ish) border and deskew the images of thousands of scanned 35mm slides.

I can successfully run commands such as

```
mogrify -fuzz 35% -deskew 80% -trim +repage *.tif
```

The problem is:-

- The border is not crisply defined nor is completely black, hence the -fuzz. Some images are over-trimmed at a certain fuzz, while others are not trimmed enough.

So what I want to do is to have two passes at this, with different fuzz %, for these reasons:-

- 1st pass with a low Fuzz%. Many images will not be trimmed at all but I have found that the ones that are susceptible to over-trimming will trim Ok with low %
- Since all the images start with an identical filesize, the ones that have trimmed Ok will have a lower filesize (note these are tifs not jpgs)
- So what I need to do is set a file size condition for the second pass at higher fuzz% THAT IGNORES file sizes below a certain value and does not perform any operation.

In this way, with few errors, all the images will be trimmed correctly.

So the question
 - How can I adjust the command line to have 2 passes and to ignore a lower file size on the second pass?

I have a horrible feeling the the answer will be a script. I have no idea how to construct or set up Ubuntu to run this so if so, please can you point me to help for that also!!

Comment: What scripting languages are you familiar with?

Comment: um - none! I can construct a windows batch file but suspect that will be of no use!

Comment: While you can do a lot with the ImageMagick command-line tools, sometimes getting a good pipeline worked out is really ugly. ImageMagick, and other libraries, are available for most scripting languages.

Comment: Ok - yes I understand your point and suspected that would be the case.

Comment: So I think the questions that follow are:  1/ What does the guts of the script need to look like (ie the correct commands to perform this and 2/ How to write, save teh script in the appropriate place and execute it?

Comment: Please post a link to a few example images and your results. You may not be able to use mogrify if you have a conditional that you need to process. You will likely need to write a bash script loop over your images. Do the first process, then your test, then you second processing depending upon the test result. Posting some images may allow us to give you a better command to use.

Comment: This is still a really open-ended question. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Ok – thankyou – I have uploaded images here:-

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ai_-xoAsqwYtwRB0SyBcF3cra2nY

NOTE these are jpgs as the original tifs are 239mb each. But I’m using these as test images as it makes no difference to the trimming function.

Also Note – the command line actually used was

mogrify -background black -fuzz 10% -deskew 80% -trim +repage *.jpg

 (I had missed out the  “-background black” in the original question – but confirm this is necessary for any successful trimming)

Comment: My conclusion from these images is:-

10% Fuzz trims Images 3,6,7 are trimmed Ok, the rest not

35% Fuzz trims images 1,2,4,5 OK, and 3,6,7 are overtrimmed

… so a combination of these values will trim all images correctly.


Can I find a Fuzz value that will trim all correctly?

No! Because 15 Fuzz Overtrims Image 6 but undertrims Image 2

Comment: I don’t mind not using Mogrify – Convert will do equally well.

Comment: Apologies if this question is a bit open ended – however I do just want to achieve one end result which is correctly trimmed images.
I know that  I don’t know the correct questions to ask re scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, you could do something like the following:

Get the input filesize

```
Use convert to deskew and trim. 

Then find the new file 

Then compare the new to the old to compute the percentdifference to some percent threshold

If the percent difference is less than some threshold, then the processing did not trim enough 

So reprocess with a higher fuzz value and write over the input; otherwise keep the first one only and do not write over the old one.
```

Unix syntax.

Choose two fuzz values

Choose a percent change threshold

Create a new empty directory to hold the output (results)

```
cd
cd desktop/Originals
fuzz1=20
fuzz2=40
threshpct=10
list=`ls`
for img in $list; do
filesize=`convert -ping $img -precision 16 -format "%b" info: | sed 's/[B]*$//'`
echo "filesize=$filesize"
convert $img -background black -deskew 40% -fuzz $fuzz1% ../results/$img
newfilesize=`convert -ping ../results/$img -precision 16 -format "%b" info: | sed 's/[B]*$//'`
test=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:100*($filesize-$newfilesize)/$filesize<$threshpct?1:0]" info:`
echo "newfilesize=$newfilesize; test=$test;"
[ $test -eq 1 ] && convert $img -background black -deskew 40% -fuzz $fuzz2% ../results/$img
done
```

The issue is that you need to be sure you set your TIFF compression for the output the same as for the input so that the file sizes are equivalent and presumably the new size is not larger than the old one as happens with JPG.

Note that the sed is used to remove the letter B (bytes) from the file size, so they can be compared as numerals and not strings. The -precision 16 forces "%b" to report as B and not KB or MB.

Comment: I believe the compression automatically defaults to the same as the input file.

Comment: The filesize is probably more simply obtained with `filesize=$(wc -c < "$img")`

Comment: Ok! This looks interesting – really interesting.

Couple of things to clarify

1/ No need to worry about compression. These are uncompressed tif’s and they can remain as such. In fact – for these purposes, it’s easier if they do I should think – as there would be no filesize variability introduced. I’ll compress them after all the trimming

Comment: 2/ The sequence of events needs to be
- Process ALL files at a given Fuzz value. Probably better if this IS Mogrify as it will happen to all files (I will have backup copies elsewhere)
- Then, only process certain files at the higher Fuzz based on Filesize criteria. This probably needs to be “”convert” not Mogrify.
- Once done, I’ll simple copy and replace the “Convert” files back into the original folders.

I’m not sure that the script suggested follows that sequence – though as you can tell – I’m not familiar enough with the syntax to be sure?